# ExtJS restrict use of base components

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I am using ExtJS 5.1 in my application.

I have created a generic MyLoadMask component by extending the Ext.LoadMask.

Now in my application I want to make sure all the developers are using MyLoadMask component. I want to restrict the usage of Ext.LoadMask.

Is there a proper way to handle in the code of application ?

Thanks!

Comment: What about a ExtJs override of the class? http://moduscreate.com/writing-ext-js-overrides/